# How can i remove a certain object from array in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have tree of checkboxes . Departments and under each department there are some checkboxes for employees. when user check on department all employees are selected under this department. I add the unique departments keys to an array. 
My problem is how to remove the unchecked department key from the array.

```
$scope.leftdept = function (m) {

        console.log(m);

        for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.depts.indexOf(m[i].Dep_key) === -1) {
                $scope.depts.push(m[i].Dep_key);
            }

       console.log($scope.depts);
    }
```

Comment: do you want to remove that entire department from the array or just only the key of that department?

Comment: if you just want to remove a key from the object, you can do this `delete Object[key]; ` in your for loop while checking if they have unchecked department or not.

Comment: i just want to remove the key, kindly can you show me a full example, thanks lot

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove the key of object then you can do it this way:

```
m.forEach(function (dept) {

if(condition) // this is where you check if this department is checked or unchecked
    delete dept[Dep_key];
});
```

Of course this only a vague example, I will need to know your actual object definition to give you a proper answer.